# Splitting string into array of words using Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split a string into an array of words, however I want to keep the spaces after each word.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
var re = /[a-z]+[$\s+]/gi;
var test = "test   one two     three   four ";
var results = test.match(re);
```

The results I expect are:

```
[0]: "test   "
[1]: "one "
[2]: "two     "
[3]: "three   "
[4]: "four "
```

However, it only matches up to one space after each word:

```
[0]: "test "
[1]: "one "
[2]: "two "
[3]: "three "
[4]: "four "
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you need to keep the space, why add `$` and `+` in the second class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider:

```
var results = test.match(/\S+\s*/g);
```

That would guarantee you don't miss any characters (besides a few spaces at the beginnings, but `\S*\s*` can take care of that)

Your original regex reads:

- `[a-z]+` - match any number of letters (at least one)
- `[$\s+]` - much a single character - `$`, `+` or whitespace. With no quantifier after this group, you only match a single space.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
test.match(/\w+\s+/g); // \w = words, \s = white spaces
```

Comment: Or if the last bit of whitespace is optional: `test.match(/\w+\s*/gi)`

Comment: @Wolph: why the case-insensitive flag?

Comment: This will split "I'm coding" into "I", "m" and "coding".

Comment: @DanDascalescu: no specific reason, more of a habit really

Comment: This works bad, and "eats" words if you try the following sentence: *The moon is our natural satellite, i.e. it rotates around the Earth!*

Answer (score 1):

You are using `+` inside the char class. Try using `*` outside the char class instead.

```
/[a-z]+\s*/gi;
```

`+` inside the char class is treated as a literal `+` and not as a meta char.
Using `*` will capture zero or more spaces that might follow any word.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` is taken literally inside the character class. You have to move it outside: `[\s]+` or just `\s+` (`$` has no meaning inside the class either).

Answer (score 0):

The essential bit of your RegEx that needs changing is the part matching the whitespace or end-of-line.

Try:

```
var re = /[a-z]+($|\s+)/gi
```

or, for [non-capturing groups](http://javascript.about.com/library/blre16.htm) (I don't know if you need this with the `/g` flag):

```
var re = /[a-z]+(?:$|\s+)/gi
```