# Javascript Split String by word count

Tags: javascript, string, split

I'm trying to **split the string by word count**, the below example is split by **character count**.

eg. I have 25 words of content.

```
var text = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
    Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. 
    Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur.`


var part1 =  text.substr(0, text.substr(0, text.length > 100 ? 100 : text.length ).lastIndexOf(" "));

var part2 =  text.substr(text.substr(0, text.length > 100 ? 100 : text.length ).lastIndexOf(" "));

console.log(part1);
console.log(part2);
```

the output will be like this : 
part 1

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor
```

part 2

```
Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur.
```

How to achieve the same output by word count, like **10 words** in part 1 and remaining in part 2

**note: The format of the content should print as it is.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548527/splitting-string-into-array-of-words-using-regular-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can do it.  I first split all the words by space (assuming that is how you want to split words).  Once I have an array of words, I then iterate over all them and check the index to see if it belongs in part1 or part2.  Finally, I return both parts in an array so that both can be extracted upon calling.

```js
const splitWords = (text, numWords) => {
  const words = text.split(' ')
  let part1 = '', part2 = ''
  words.forEach((word, idx) => {
    if (idx < numWords) {
       part1 += ' ' + word
    } else {
        part2 += ' ' + word 
    }
  })
  return [part1.trim(), part2.trim()]
}

const [ part1, part2 ] = splitWords(text, 25)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the format of the content should be as it is, while print part1 and part2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. Words splitted by spaces and spliced in the middle. Array is then joined back together with spaces.

```js
    var text = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. 
Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur.`

    
    let part2=text.split(' ').filter(Boolean);
    let part1=part2.splice(0,(part2.length/2)+1).join(" ")
    part2=part2.join(" ")
    
    console.log(part1);
    console.log(part2);
```